# Fullscreen terminal ouput from PHP (similar to watch)

Tags: php, terminal

I'm trying to build a tool in PHP that will monitor a service and output the status to a terminal. I'd like to print a lot of information that will take up most the the terminal, so when it refreshes the information, it should replace the previous content rather than adding to it.

How can I control the output from a PHP script like that? Is Ncurses the only way?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve is is to just clear the screen - of course this is not the most beautiful solution.

As you just said [ncurses](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ncurses.php) is the only way to do it -  and it is sure the best way to do it regarding your requirements.